# Cannot create custom windows phone control

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I am trying to create a custom template control for my `Windows Phone 8.1` project but whatever I do it gives me the following exception:

> Failed to create a 'System.Type' from the text
>   'local2:CustomControl1'.

I really appreciate any help. Here is my current code

**PivotPage.xaml:**

```
    <Page
        x:Class="App1.PivotPage"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:controls="using:App1.Controls"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:data="using:App1.Data"
        xmlns:local="using:App1"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
        DataContext="{Binding DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <controls:CustomControl1 />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**CustomControl1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Documents;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;

// The Templated Control item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234235

namespace App1.Controls
{
    public sealed class CustomControl1 : Control
    {
        public CustomControl1()
        {
            this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CustomControl1);
        }
    }
}
```

**Generic.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1">

    <Style TargetType="local2:CustomControl1" xmlns:local2="using:App1.Controls">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local2:CustomControl1">
                    <Border
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App1" xmlns:local2="using:App1.Controls">

<Style TargetType="local2:CustomControl1" >
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local2:CustomControl1">
                <Border
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Altough this code works I don't know why the above one doesn't. I mean it's a self generated one when I click create template control. Is this a bug or something?

Comment: I dont think it auto-generated the code like that,if it did then that should be a bug.

Comment: this is a completely new solution. I just created the template control and run the application. The result is here. So its probably a bug as you said. Thanks for your help.